# Why does stacked barplot ggplot in R sum values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I make the following, I want just to compare the three years not to sum them. And the actual code sums them even if I don't tell it to do it. Any clue?

```
hoteles <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Hotel          , ~Año, ~Ingresos
  , "Hawaiian Club" , "1993",    450000
  , "Hawaiian Club" , "1994",    475000
  , "Hawaiian Club" , "1995",    390000
  , "French Riviera", "1993",    225000
  , "French Riviera", "1994",    240000
  , "French Riviera", "1995",    205000
  , "Bahamas Beach" , "1993",    245000
  , "Bahamas Beach" , "1994",    255000
  , "Bahamas Beach" , "1995",    345000
)

g <- ggplot(hoteles, aes(fill=Año, y=Ingresos, x=reorder(Hotel, Ingresos))) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  ggtitle("Ingresos por año por hotel") +
  labs(y = "Ingresos", x = "Hotel")
g
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: You drew stacked bars, but don't want the values to be summed? It's unclear what else you would want to happen instead—maybe you didn't actually mean to stack them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this:

```
ggplot(hoteles, aes(fill=Año, y=Ingresos, x=reorder(Hotel, Ingresos))) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge")+
  ggtitle("Ingresos por año por hotel") +
  labs(y = "Ingresos", x = "Hotel")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

[image]